# Nordic Nrf52840 ports

Tags: port, pins

I know this is a likely a dumb question but if you can set Port0.5
with   NRF_GPIO->OUTSET = 1UL << 5;

what is the equivalent statement for setting Port1.5?

Thanks.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

OK - Figured it out - I think.  In the 52840 there are two ports. Other
devices only had one.  I saw something where NRF_GPIO was renamed NRF_P0.
I tried NRF_P1->OUTSET = 1UL << 5; and it compiled successfuly.